# Android XML adapted for all scree sizes

Tags: size, screen

I am currently developing an android application and am facing a problem.

I am aware that the most common thing to adapt your application to most of the devices is to create different folder named "layout-small", "layout-normal", etc. in order to handle this issue.

However, this does not solve everything : both Samsung S2 and Samsung S3 and considered "normal" screen size, but the given result is very different, even though I also use "dp" to set height and with of most of my views.

How can I adapt my xml for EVERY device PERFECTLY ? I don't mind having the same xml file for every different device, but how do I do that ?

Here is an example of an XML file that renders welle on S3, but is cut down on S2 (the last button appears partially)

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Me"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            style="@style/title_parameters"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btUpdateProfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Update profile"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selected_parameters"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/solo_button_parameters"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/table_view_cell_accessory_disclosure_indicator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@style/title_parameters"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btUpdateProfile"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFindFriends"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Find friends"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selected_parameters"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/solo_button_parameters"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/table_view_cell_accessory_disclosure_indicator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"/>


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Setting"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@style/title_parameters"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btFindFriends"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btSharing"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Sharing"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selected_parameters"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/top_corner_button_parameters"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/table_view_cell_accessory_disclosure_indicator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btPushNotification"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selected_parameters"
            android:text="Push notification"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_button_parameters"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/table_view_cell_accessory_disclosure_indicator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btSharing"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btAutomation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Automation"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_corner_button_parameters"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/table_view_cell_accessory_disclosure_indicator"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btPushNotification"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selected_parameters"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btDisconnect"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Disconect"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selected_parameters"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:background="@drawable/solo_button_parameters"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/disconnect"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btAutomation"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I will upload screen shots as soon as I can.

Once again, my question is : how can I have an XML file for every existing device ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post some code. It will be better.
Without define fixed size relative layout and use its positional attributes properly.  (This is a comment )

Comment: I can't post code, there isn't enough space, but basically, what happened with one of the xml file was that it renders well on S3, but the S2 screen is NOT long enough to display all the buttons !

Comment: Give the parent layout attribute `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"` and later on adjust the remaining component accordingly. can you please upload a screen-shot in your question?